# Updated RubyGems: uninitialized constant Gem::ConfigFile::RbConfig

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

After Updating RubyGems from version 1.3.5 => 1.8.19 every time I try to add a new gem I get this:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:71:in `rescue in rescue in <class:ConfigFile>': uninitialized constant Gem::ConfigFile::RbConfig (NameError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:53:in `rescue in <class:ConfigFile>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:49:in `<class:ConfigFile>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:9:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/gem:9:in `require'
from /usr/local/bin/gem:9:in `<main>'
```

I double checked that my /usr/local/bin/gem file has `require 'rubygems/gem_runner'` under `require 'ruby gems'`

So not sure why I'm getting this error, before it installed gems perfectly.

Comment: wget source and make installed it

Comment: I suspect this could be the problem. Try using something else such as rvm or rbenv instead.

Comment: I get the same error using rvm and ruby 1.9.1-p376

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, it was a ruby version mismatch with ruby gems. Upgrade fixed it.
Thanks